# What will be the output of this program and how?

Tags: c, macros

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define ABS(a,b)                \
do {                            \
(a>0) ? b = a : (b = -a);       \
return b;                       \
}while(0)                       \

int main()
{
int a = -2, b;
ABS(a,b);
printf("a=%d b=%d\n", a, b);
}
```

I can't able to understand the output of this. Please explain. Thanks

Comment: you could run this yourself and see what the output is... *shrug*

Comment: What output is there to speak of?

Comment: That is super-strange, why does the macro have a `return`in it? It's going to immediately exit `main()`, passing `-2` to the surrounding environment.

Comment: You have to check your macro function `ABS(a,b)` that is causing the problem.

Comment: Please learn how to indent code.

Comment: If you don't understand the output, you should at least tell us what you have tried so far to get a solution and where you are stuck.

Comment: What is `ABS(x,y)` supposed to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will not produce any output.  For the macro, the defined code will replace the macro call, resulting in the following program:

```
int main()
{
    int a = -2, b;

    do {
        (a>0) ? b = a : (b = -a);
        return b;
    }while(0)

    printf("a=%d b=%d\n", a, b);
}
```

As you can see, the code will `return` prior to reaching the `printf()`.

If you want to fix this so that it sets `b` to the absolute value of `a`:

```
#define ABS(a,b) ((a)>0) ? ((b) = (a)) : ((b) = -(a))


int main()
{
    int a = -2, b;
    ABS(a, b);
    printf("a=%d b=%d\n", a, b);
}
```

output:

```
a=-2 b=2
```

It's a good idea to always place macro parameters inside parentheses in case they are more complex values that may have specific order of operations requirements.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest explanation is to unpack the macro. If you do that you get

```
int main()
{
    int a = -2, b;
    do {
        (a>0) ? b = a : (b = -a);
        return b;
    } while(0);
    printf("a=%d b=%d\n", a, b);
}
```

So you can see `return b;` will exit the program before the `printf` is reached, outputting `2` back to the command shell. The moral of the story is to minimise the use of macros.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is an assignment for school? But I'll help you understand it a bit.

The main function, as you might know, is the entry point of the application. There, a is defined, b is not, so b will be 0 or a "random" value (dependent on the compiler). ABS has been defined as a macro, causing ABS(a, b) to be replaced by the do, while operation.

Since a is not bigger than 0, as the condition "(a>0)" relies on the value, to either cause b to get the value of a. or b to get the value of a.

Simply put, it sets b's value to |a| (abstract value of a a.k.a always positive)

The while(0) is senseless and does nothing, if not cause the do to not be executed again.

As there's a return in the macro the program will not output anything. Because the application will be exited before the printf.

Comment: Due to a special rule in the C standard about unitialzed objects, `b` does not necessarily have any value at all. First, using it while unitialized may cause a trap—the standard says the behavior is undefined. Second, if it does not cause a trap, it may behave as if it has a different value each time it is referenced. This is not applicable to the code in the question since it does not use `b` before assigning it a value, but your statement about the initial value of `b` is incorrect.

Comment: The `while(0)` is not senseless. It is needed to complete the `do`, which is used to make the macro have a statement-like grammar. This is a common practice to define a macro that can be used in a place where a statement can appear in C, including a terminating semicolon.

Comment: @EricPostpischil The `do { ... } while(0)` trick _is_ quite senseless, but not for the reason given in this answer. The _only_ purpose of this trick is to encourage "Apple goto fail" coding style: `if(something) MACRO(); else ...` rather than bug-free style: `if(something) { MACRO(); } else ...` Replacing `do { ... } while(0)` with the more correct `{ ... }` will give compiler errors when crappy coding styles are used, which is preferred in professional software.

Comment: @Lundin: The “Apple goto fail” bug involved [a duplicated line](https://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2014/02/24/anatomy-of-a-goto-fail-apples-ssl-bug-explained-plus-an-unofficial-patch/), not a macro invocation.

Comment: @EricPostpischil The root cause of the bug was the same dangerous coding style that do-while(0) macros encourage.